# my production code stopped compiling after moving to visual studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2019, friend

The following simple application demonstrates the compile error:
My class declaration: MyClass.h

```
#pragma once
class MyClass
{
   friend int MyCalc();
public:
};
```

class definition: MyClass.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MyClass.h"

int MyCalc()
{
   return 1 + 2;
}
```

The main function: ConsoleApplication1.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MyClass.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   std::cout << MyCalc();//"Identifier MyCalc is undefined" in Visual Studio 2019, but not in 2015
    return 0;
}
```

I'm guessing the updated c++ version has made this more restrictive.
So will I have to add a declaration of the function outside of the class everywhere I have a friend function declared, like so:

```
class MyClass
{
   friend int MyCalc();
public:
};
int MyCalc();
```

Comment: C++ has been that way for a long while.

Comment: Visual Studio's C++ compiler had bugs that are fixed in 2019.

Comment: Try turning off precompiled headers.  You don't need them for small programs.

Comment: Current C/C++ setting = "Not Using Precompiled Headers"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the clause, found in `[namespace.memdef]`, that is causing the name `MyCalc()` not to be found inside `main()`, and it has been part of standard C++ for as long as there has been a C++ Standard.

> Every name first declared in a namespace is a member of that namespace. If a friend declaration in a non-local class first declares a class or function the friend class or function is a member of the innermost enclosing namespace. **The name of the friend is not found by simple name lookup until a matching declaration is provided in that namespace scope** (either before or after the class declaration granting friendship).

Older versions of the Visual C++ compiler may not have enforced this rule correctly, but your code is in error and always has been and Visual Studio 2019 is correct to tell you this.

Comment: I would appreciate it if someone would check for this rule in C++98.

Comment: That same wording is in C++98 (section 7.3.1.2, paragraph 3).